# scala apache access log regex not working

Tags: regex, scala, matching

I have defined regex for apache access log as below:

`val apacheLogPattern = """
^(\S+) (\S+) (\S+) \[([\w:/]+\s[+\-]\d{4})\] "(\S+)\s?(\S+)?\s?(\S+)?" (\d{3}|-) (\d+|-)\s?"?([^"]*)"?\s?"?([^"]*)?"?$
""".r`

And a function to parse the log:

```
def parse_log(line: String) = {
    line match {
       case apacheLogPattern(ipAddress, clientIdentity, userId, dateTime, method, endPoint, 
        protocol, responseCode, contentSize, browser, somethingElse) => "match"
    }
}

val p = """66.249.69.97 - - [24/Sep/2014:22:25:44 +0000] "GET /071300/242153 HTTP/1.1" 404 514 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; Googlebot/2.1; +http://www.google.com/bot.html)"""
```

`parse_log(p)`

Calling the parse function gives MatchError

scala.MatchError:
66.249.69.97 - - [24/Sep/2014:22:25:44 +0000] "GET /071300/242153 HTTP/1.1" 404 514 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; Googlebot/2.1; +http://www.google.com/bot.html)"
 (of class java.lang.String)
  at .parse_log(:13)
  ... 28 elided

Can someone help me where the scala regex is going wrong?

Comment: You have to add `.r` and you have 11 groups in the regex but are pattern matching only 10. See https://ideone.com/lRqyQp Do you need all those capturing groups?

Comment: Thanks @Thefourthbird for the code. Its working now

Comment: Thanks @Emma for your input

Answer (score 1):

From [The fourth bird's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58041443/scala-apache-access-log-regex-not-working#comment102483471_58041443), the regex is lacking `.r` at the end, and has one too many capturing groups. The correct pattern is shown below.

```scala
val apacheLogPattern = """^(\S+) (\S+) (\S+) \[([\w:/]+\s[+\-]\d{4})\] "(\S+)\s?(\S+)?\s?(\S+)?" (\d{3}|-) (\d+|-)\s?"?([^"]*)"?\s?"?([^"]*)?"?$""".r
```